# Jersey test framework - InMemoryTestContainer - JNDI support

Tags: testing, jersey, containers, in-memory

I am using Jersey's InMemoryTestContainer for testing my small REST application. Now I am creating my datasource object and binding it to the context in the `start()` of the **InMemoryTestContainer** as below:

```
    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (!webApp.isInitiated()) {
            logger.info("Starting low level InMemory test container");

            try {
                //Create datasource and bind it  
                initDataSource();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            webApp.initiate(resourceConfig, new GuiceComponentProviderFactory(resourceConfig, injector) {
                @Override
                public Map<Scope, ComponentScope> createScopeMap() {
                    Map<Scope, ComponentScope> m = super.createScopeMap();

                    m.put(ServletScopes.REQUEST, ComponentScope.PerRequest);
                    return m;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

In tomcat we will create the datasource by putting information in context.xml, Is there any standard way like that with InMemoryTestContainer ?